# Image.network() from Firebase Storage works in Chrome, fails in Android

Tags: flutter, firebase, image, firebase-storage

I am loading a NetworkImage from a URL that is in Firebase Storage. Running the same code from vscode without touching it...

Device: Chrome -> it works totally fine

Device: Android emulator -> it fails with the below error

Device: Android physical phone -> it fails with the below error

But strangely, when I run the app that remains on my Android device from the debugging session, it works totally fine. This part has me particularly stumped. Somehow the debugger is affecting it?

Has anyone faced something similar and/or have suggestions on what debugging path may be more fruitful?

Example code:

```
class RepImage extends StatelessWidget {
  const RepImage({super.key, required this.repId});
  final String repId;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: repImageUrl(repId),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        Widget widget;
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          widget = const Icon(Icons.person, size: 60);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          widget = const Icon(Icons.error);
        } else {
          widget = Image.network(snapshot.data!);
        }

        return Center(
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            child: widget,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

Future<String> repImageUrl(repId) async {
  String path = '/images/rep';
  String filename = '${repId}_120px.png';
  Reference ref = storageRef(path, filename);

  return storageUrl(ref);
}

Future<String> storageUrl(Reference ref) async {
  var url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
  return url;
}

Reference storageRef(path, filename) {
  Reference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(path).child(filename);
  return ref;
}
```

Error:

```
E/StorageException(29922): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(29922): Object does not exist at location.
E/StorageException(29922):  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException(29922): {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
E/StorageException(29922): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found."  }}
E/StorageException(29922):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:445)
E/StorageException(29922):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(NetworkRequest.java:462)
E/StorageException(29922):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(NetworkRequest.java:453)
E/StorageException(29922):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:272)
E/StorageException(29922):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:289)
```

Comment: in your function `repImageUrl(repId)`, line`Reference ref = storageRef(path, filename);`
 is await required?

Comment: Hi @WiCheung, thanks for trying to help. I believe `await` is not required because it is all being passed back to a `FutureBuilder` which ultimately does the awaiting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of figured it out, and it's pretty obnoxious, but it turns out that code that works on other platforms works totally different on Android. The checks I do for data and for error after `getDownloadURL()` are great on Web, but on Android, the underlying lib throws errors rather than packing them into the returned object.

It occurred to me that the reason that it works when just running the app on my physical device is because it will ignore those thrown errors and attempt to proceed.

To get it to work in debugging as well, I caught the thrown errors when calling `getDownloadURL()`, as follows...

```
Future<String?> storageUrl(Reference ref) async {
  String? url;
  try {
    url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
  } catch (error) {
    print("----- caught error from getDownloadURL: $error");
    url = null;
  }

  return url;
}
```

Much to my disappointment, there is not a way to check the reference (i.e. `ref.exists`) for validity prior to requesting the download URL.